# Dynamic Field Name in SSRS

Tags: sql-server, variables, dynamic, reporting-services

I'm trying to Retrieve a value of a field, but that name of the field needs to be dynamic.

i.e.

```
=iif(Fields!Year1.Value = 1, 0, 1)
```

But I need the `Year1` part to be returned from another dataset, so the `Year1` is dynamic (could be `Year2`, `Year3` etc....)

I have a field that returns the data

```
 =First(Fields!YearCount.Value, "YearColumn").
```

This expression in itself will return the `Year1`, `Year2` etc.. part, however I am struggling to concatenate this with the if statement.

I have tried:

```
=iif(Fields!(First(Fields!YearCount.Value, "YearColumn")).Value = 1, 0, 1)
```

for example.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The notation to reference a field in SSRS is either:

```
=Fields!FieldName
```

or then

```
=Fields(FieldName)
```

So in your case, try this:

```
=Fields(First(Fields!YearCount.Value, "YearColumn")).Value
```

because the *inner* function should return `Year1` (or another value), you should get an expression like:

```
=Fields("Year1").Value
```

and that should give you your value you need.

Comment: thank you very much, it worked and helped a tremendous amount.

Comment: @jjm: glad I was able to help! I'm currently also getting into SSRS and boy - it's quite a beast and quite unintuitive at times...

Comment: There is the single answer in Internet space and there are no votes. Very bad, people!! @marc_s, thank you very much!

Comment: Holy... wow, this exists?! Goodbye, humongous `Switch()` statement. Thanks, both!